# what's wrong with my variable, it's undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

my variable todoHtmlLi is undefined, really can't get it why.. I had declared it early before assign it to some html. I use console.log() to check the priority value, it work just fine..

```
$(document).on('click', '#addTodoBtn', function () {
    var todoDialog = {
        state0: {
            html: dialogContent,
            buttons: {
                Cancel: -1,
                Add: 0
            },
            focus: 1,
            submit: function (e, v, m, f) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var todoHtmlLi;
                var todoNameVal;
                var todoNoteVal;

                //Task Name
                todoNameVal = $("#todoName").val();
                todoNameVal.trim();

                //Note
                todoNoteVal = $("#todoNote").val();
                todoNoteVal.trim();

                //Priority 
                priority = $("#priority").val();

                if ($(priority) === 1) {
                    todoHtmlLi = "<li style='background:red'><a href='#'>" + todoNameVal + "<input type='checkbox'></a></li>"
                } else if ($(priority) === 2) {
                    todoHtmlLi = "<li style='background:green'><a href='#'>" + todoNameVal + "<input type='checkbox'></a></li>"
                } else if ($(priority) === 3) {
                    todoHtmlLi = "<li style='background:blue'><a href='#'>" + todoNameVal + "<input type='checkbox'></a></li>"
                }

                if (v == 0) {
                    if (todoNameVal !== "") {

                        $("div#tab").find('#todoUl').prepend(todoHtmlLi);

                        $.prompt.close();

                    } else {
                        $("#todoName").focus();
                    }

                } else {
                    $.prompt.close();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    $.prompt(todoDialog);
});
```

if(v == 0){ mean the 'yes' button is clicked

Comment: which line you get the undefiend?

Comment: whats $(priority)..? may be its not set to 1, 2 or 3..? in that case todoHtmlLi will be undefined..!

Comment: @liad I put alert(todoHtmlLi) on the line of if(v == 0), it pop up undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: You only assign values to `todoHtmlLi` based on comparing the return value of a call to `val()` (which will be a String) to a Number using `===` (which checks type).

Since `"1" === 1` is not true, you never assign a value.

Either use `==`, compare to Strings or convert to a Number.

**Second**: You pass the value as an argument to `$`, so you get a jQuery object back instead of that String. This doesn't make any sense, so don't do that.

```
if (priority == 1){
if (priority === "1"){
if (parseInt(priority,10) === 1){
```

Comment: what is the diff btw == and ====?

Comment: `===` checks types, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Because your `conditions` are wrong.

see ,

```
  priority = $("#priority").val();
```

That `returns` a `string`.

Then

```
  if($(priority) === 1){
```

That is wrong ,Since `1`  never equals to `"1"`,So no condition satisfied.and it;s `undefined`.

Your if condition should be

```
   if(priority === "1"){
```

And also remaining if conditions needs to be change.

Comment: I corrected my mistake, but it did not solve the problem.. the variable still undefined

Comment: @JohannClemons Have you checked that,Any of the conditions becoming true ?